# GameCenter match making according to same preference value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center

I'm developing a game that has different difficulty levels, and I want to allow multiplayer on either the "hard" or "expert" mode. I know that there is the `playerAttributes` property on the `GKMatchRequest` object that matches players so that no two players have the same bits for `playerAttributes`. Is there a way of manipulating this to only find players that have the SAME `playerAttributes` value? Or more likely, some slick way of assigning different `playerAttributes` that somehow will match two players who want to play the same difficulty level?

Or, better still, is there another way, without using `playerAttributes`, to match only players who want to play the same difficulty level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I totally overlooked the `playerGroup` attribute which does exactly what I wanted. Oh well.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html